# Prove the probability of extracting the i'th ball from an urn without replacements will be have a certain color is contant

Tags: probability

Given an urn with n balls, b of them are black and the rest are white, what is the probability to get a black ball on the i'th extraction (without replacements)
I've found other answers saying that the probability should remain constant, and is $b/n$
But I haven't found a good proof for that.

I've thought of using induction, assuming that that
P(black ball on every k<i ball)=$b/n$.
This will lead to the number of black balls extracted so far will have a binomial distribution, and then use the law of total probability and calculate-

$$p(ith-is-a-black-ball)=\sum\limits_{l=0}^{i-1}\frac{b-l}{n-i-1}{i-1\choose l}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^l\left(\frac{n-b}{n}\right)^{i-l-i}$$

but I couldn't get this expression to be equal to $b/n$

Comment: In the first line you state "j of them are black. But I suspect that is a typo and should be "b of them are black".

Comment: you're right @drhab, I've changed that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest, I think, to imagine that the balls were labeled $\{b_1, b_2,\cdots, r_1,r_2\cdots\}$ and then note that "random" here means that each ball is equally likely to be taken in any particular draw.

To do it by induction:

Suppose we have $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls.

Let $P_i(r,b)$ denote the probability that the $i^{th}$ draw is red.

If $r+b$ is small, $1$, $2$, or $3$,  say, it is easy to verify that $P_i$ does not depend on $i$.

We proceed by induction on $n=r+b$.  Specifically, we suppose that, for all $r,b$ with $r+b<n$ we have shown that $$P_i(r,b)=\frac r{r+b}$$
for all $i$.

We now consider $r,b$ such that $r+b=n$  Of course $P_1(r,b)=\frac r{r+b}$.  Suppose then that $i>1$.  Considering the outcome of the first draw we see that $$P_i(r,b)=\frac r{r+b}\times P_{i-1}(r-1,b)+\frac b{r+b}\times P_{i-1}(r,b-1)$$

Of course the inductive hypothesis applies on the right so we deduce that $$P_i(r,b)=\frac r{r+b}\times \frac {r-1}{r+b-1}+\frac b{r+b}\times \frac r{r+b-1}=\frac r{r+b}$$

and we are done

Comment: I understand your use of the law of total probability, but on the n'th draw, it looks like you're assuming that you're choosing a ball from r+b balls, but this value changes over each draw. Did i got that right?

Comment: I consider the $i^{th}$ draw with $(r,b)$ balls.  I argue that after the first draw this becomes either the $(i-1)^{st}$ draw with $(r-1,b)$ or the $(i-1)^{st}$ draw with $(r,b-1)$ balls and both of those cases are covered by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: But, really,  the proof provided in the first sentence is better.  The induction argument works but the final really seems to drop out by algebraic accident.  Still worth understanding the induction, of course, as intuitive arguments in probability can be unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

> "I've found other answers saying that the probability should remain constant, and is $b/n$. But I haven't found a good proof for that."

I hope that this proof will convince you.

---

Label the balls with numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ in such a way that the black balls have the numbers $1,2,\dots,b$.

Let $E_k$ denote the event that the ball with number $k$ is drawn by the $i$-th draw.

These events are mutually exclusive and covering, so that:$$\sum_{k=1}^nP(E_k)=1\tag1$$
The probability that a ball will be drawn as $i$-th ball will evidently not depend on its label so:$$P(E_1)=P(E_2)=\cdots=P(E_n)\tag2$$

Based on $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find that: $$P(E_k)=\frac1n\text{ for every }k\in\{1,2,\dots,20\}$$

Then finally:$$P(\text{black ball is drawn as }i\text{-th ball})=P(E_1\cup\cdots\cup E_b)=\sum_{k=1}^bP(E_k)=\sum_{k=1}^b\frac1n=\frac{b}{n}$$

Comment: On every extraction we have one less ball. isn't that mean that $P(E_k)=1/(n-i)$?

Comment: Do you agree that the ball with e.g. **label** 3 has the same probability to become the $i$-th drawn ball as the ball with - let's say - **label** 9? That is the essence. Why should just a label have any influence on that probability?...

Comment: I agree that each label has the same probability to be chosen on the i'th draw/ But when you get to the i'th draw, the total number of balls left is $n-i$, and the total number of black balls left is unknown. So I understand why P(black ball is drawn on ith draw) is equal to the union of $E_1$ to $E_n$

Comment: The observation that every label has the same probability ( hence has probability 1/n) is done before we start drawing. At that time we find that the probability that a black ball will be drawn as $i$-th ball must be b/n. How things evolve during drawing has no influence on an observation that was already made.

Answer (score 0):

The probability on each extraction is $b/n$, but the events are not independent. The distribution of balls chosen so far is not binomial.

If the distribution were binomial, there would be a $(b/n)^n >0$ probability of drawing $n$ black balls if $0<b<n,$ whereas the actual probability is zero.